# How to fetch the name from consoled output to HTML page using Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a select option, in which the names of companies must be displayed in drop-down. Can anyone help me to fetch the names to HTML from consoled output.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="selected" [(ngModel)]="selectedCampaign" >
          <option *ngFor="let item of CampaignData" [ngValue]="item">{{item.campaign_name}}</option>
        </select>
```

Typescript:

```
this.usersTableService.getCompanyData(this.token).subscribe(companies => {
    this.data = companies;
    this.companiesPDF = companies;
    var CampaignData = this.companiesPDF;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(companies));
  });
  }
```

Consoled Output:

> [
>       {"CVR":3456789,"name":"Benz","address":"34 rue du bourbier","phoneNo":633406546,"email":"claire.malinet@iae-aix.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":18,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>
> {"CVR":1234567,"name":"Stefania's
>   local","address":"Norre Alle
>   8","phoneNo":485698659,"email":"stefania.b.wiredelta@gmail.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":20,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>
> {"CVR":2365986,"name":"Churchdesk","address":"Kobenvan
>   32","phoneNo":25362536,"email":"stefaniabarabas@gmail.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":23,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>
> {"CVR":78945665,"name":"Peergrade","address":"Titangae
>   11, 2200
>   Kobenhavn","phoneNo":8659865,"email":"david@peergrade.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":25,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>
> {"CVR":85968596,"name":"Bosch","address":"Norre
>   Alle 7, 2500
>   Kobenhavn","phoneNo":78451296,"email":"hermagold@gmail.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":27,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>
> {"CVR":784586,"name":"Lala","address":"Kobenhavn
>   25S","phoneNo":78458526,"email":"lala@lala.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":30,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>
> {"CVR":12345678,"name":"testWD","address":"Titangade
>   11, 2200
>   København","phoneNo":34567890,"email":"claire.m.wiredelta@gmail.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":37,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":true},
>   {"CVR":12312322,"name":"Wirelocal","address":null,"phoneNo":123123123,"email":"maks.k.wiredelta@gmail.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":38,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>   {"CVR":111,"name":"AnuShree","address":null,"phoneNo":23456,"email":"anushree.s.wiredelta@gmail.com","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":39,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":false},
>
> {"CVR":38185470,"name":"Orbiz","address":"Lyskær
>   7, 1. 2730
>   Herlev","phoneNo":20638651,"email":"tandrup@orbizinsight.dk","active":true,"accessId":null,"agreementNo":null,"id":40,"postalCodeId":null,"preSurvey":true}]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your model should be accessible to your template, so based on your code, as you have used `this.data`, you can use `data` to render the data.

Second, you can render it like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="selected" [(ngModel)]="selectedCampaign" >
          <option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: @Tulsi I'm happy it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="selected" [(ngModel)]="selectedCampaign" >
  <option *ngFor="let item of companiesPDF" [ngValue]="item">{{item?.name}}</option>
</select>
```

- Right now you are accessing varibale named `CampaignData`
- also use `?` safe navigation while rendring name , it may help to avoid error while asynch data.